# Spring @Configuration @Bean and @Autowired required?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wanted to know if I add @Configuration to a spring class and add @Bean annotation to a method in that class which returns a new instance of the method. why do I have to @Autowired it in another class ? doesn't spring take care it of using @Configuration annotation? Here is the sample code for better understanding

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public MyBean myBean() {
        return new MyBean();
    }
    
}
```

```
@Component
public class MyAnotherClass {

    @Autowired
    MyBean myBean;
    

    private MyBean myBean; //why not this ? 
    
}
```

Comment: What do you want Spring to do here? If there's no injection point, how are you going to use `MyBean`?

Answer (score 1):

Your `@Configuration` establishes an instance of `MyBean` in the context.

Adding the `@Autowired` in `MyAnotherClass` tells spring you want it to inject a `MyBean` there.  You can declare the field as private if you want, e.g.:

```
@Component
public class MyAnotherClass {

    @Autowired
    private MyBean myBean;
    
}
```

FWIW, many, myself included, prefer constructor injection as it makes things a lot cleaner in terms of mutability and bean state.  E.g.:

```
@Component
public class MyAnotherClass {

    private final MyBean myBean;

    public MyAnotherClass(MyBean myBean){
        this.myBean = myBean;
    }
    
}
```

Note: you don't need `@Autowired` anywhere because you've already told spring to instantiate `MyAnotherClass` and it only has one constructor, so spring will try to use that.

For more details on different injection types, https://reflectoring.io/constructor-injection/

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have to tell Spring where to inject your beans. So that `@Autowired` is indeed required. However, you can safely omit the `@Bean` method. Spring knows how to inject `@Component` classes without you telling it how to create them.